# Validation in Laravel Spark broken after changing user fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have minimally changed the registration process - instead of `name`, I'm using `firstname` and `lastname`. No problem.

```
form: $.extend(true, new SparkForm({ 
    firstname: '', 
    lastname: '', email: '' }), 
    Spark.forms.updateContactInformation)
```

That works fine for CREATION of the user object, however upon successful registration, I want the user to fill in the rest of their profile - of which there are many new fields I'm adding.

So, in adding all the new fields to the settings page (for example, lastname), on clicking the update button, it seems something is still validating the `name`, instead of `firstname`, and I'm unsure where to put in my new fields for validation purposes.
Getting error `The name field is required.`

As per the docs, I'm using `Spark::validateUsersWith` to validate the `firstname` instead of `name`, hence the create user works - but where is the validation for updating ? I cant seem to locate that.

I can see its using `ContactInformationController@update` and confirm its being hit with some logging, however even trying explicitly

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'lastname' => 'nullable|max:255',
    ]);
```

in there doesn't do the trick - must be something in here but not sure how it works:

```
$this->interaction(
        $request, UpdateContactInformation::class,
        [$request->user(), $request->all()]
    );
```